# jboss unexpected element archive

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Tried integrating jboss with Websphere MQ

Error:

```
14:10:11,481 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -D[Standalone] -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jbosssvr/jboss-as/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jbosssvr/jboss-as/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
14:10:11,964 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.jboss.as.connector.util.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: archive                                                                                                                                                                    
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.resourceadapters.ResourceAdaptersExtension$ResourceAdapterSubsystemParser.readElement(ResourceAdaptersExtension.java:482)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.resourceadapters.ResourceAdaptersExtension$ResourceAdapterSubsystemParser.readElement(ResourceAdaptersExtension.java:211)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:894) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:330) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.connector.util.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: archive
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterParser.parseResourceAdapters(ResourceAdapterParser.java:127)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterParser.parse(ResourceAdapterParser.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.resourceadapters.ResourceAdaptersExtension$ResourceAdapterSubsystemParser.readElement(ResourceAdaptersExtension.java:474)
    ... 13 more

14:10:11,972 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
14:10:11,990 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 1ms
```

My standalone-full.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0">
    <resource-adapters>
        <archive>
            wmq.jmsra.rar
        </archive>
        <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
         <connection-definitions>
        <connection-definition 
                        class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" 
                        jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/CF" 
                        pool-name="jms/CF">
        <config-property name="channel">
                        JAVA.CHANNEL
        </config-property>
        <config-property name="transportType">
                        CLIENT
        </config-property>
        <config-property name="queueManager">
                        TEST_MRIS_IIB
        </config-property>
                        <security>
                        <security-domain>JmsXARealm</security-domain>
                        </security>
        </connection-definition>
        </connection-definitions>
        <admin-objects>
        <admin-object 
                        class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" 
                        jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/queue/Q_PVF_BACKEND" 
                        pool-name="jms/queue/Q_PVF_BACKEND">
        <config-property name="backendQueue">
                        Q_PVF_BACKEND
        </config-property>
        </admin-object>
        <admin-object 
                        class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" 
                        jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/queue/Q_MRES_PSDS_ALL_MSG" 
                        pool-name="jms/queue/Q_MRES_PSDS_ALL_MSG">
        <config-property name="jobQueue">
                        Q_MRES_PSDS_ALL_MSG
        </config-property>
        </admin-object>
        </admin-objects>
    </resource-adapters>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have a typo in your *standalone-full.xml* file since you're missing the `<resource-adapter>` definition tag.

You should have something like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0">
    <resource-adapters>
        <resource-adapter>
            <archive>wmq.jmsra.rar</archive>

            (...)

        </resource-adapter>
    </resource-adapters>
</subsystem>
```

Take a closer look at [JBoss Resource Adapters docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Resource+adapters) for further information.

Comment: thanks for the help! i'm able to start jboss server now

Answer (score 0):

I have faced issues but finally found the solution, that i was missing

```
<archive>wmq.jmsra.rar</archive>
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question since OP has this in config